# What is the equivalent jQuery code to the following JavaScript which saves off onclick events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So in JavaScript I can do the following:

```
var someObj = document.getElementById("foo");
var fooClick = foo.onclick;

var someOtherObj = document.getElementById("bar");
someOtherObj.onclick = fooClick;
```

I'm wondering, what is the jQuery equivalent to the code above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var someObj = $("#foo").get(0);
var fooClick = someObj.onclick;

$("#bar").click(fooClick);
```

or if you want this in one line:

```
$("#bar").click($("#foo").get(0).onclick);
```

Answer (score 6):

Is it really required that you get the event handler from another object? That doesn't seem like a great idea to me. A better way would be to define the handler, and assign it to both objects.

```
var clickHandler = function(e) { alert('click!'); };
$('#foo,#bar').click(clickHandler);
```

Comment: I agree with this advice +1, my example gives asker exactly what they asked for, however he/she should consider just binding the same handler to both in the first place as you recommend.

Comment: Thanks, yours is +1'd for answering the question :D

Comment: Yep, you guys are right... that would be better.  However I'm trying save off a click event for an object which renders from the server side with with this click event.  So, I have no control over how it renders and can't get the dynamically created javascript until it gets to the client side :(

Comment: OOOH that's ugly! My condolences! David's answer is what you're looking for, then

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to Daniel Schaffer's answer (+1'd), you can also inline your click 'handler' definition, for example:

```
$("#foo, #bar").click( function() {
    alert( this.id + ' was clicked.' );
} );
```

The behaviour should be the same, but depending on your coding style taste, you may prefer this (I do).